# How to get length by children collactions with Cypress?

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I use Cypress.io with ReactJs

i have the html structure

```
<ul class="wrapper">
  <li class="class-1">1</li>
  <li class="class-2">2</li>
  <li class="class-3">3</li>
  <li class="class-4">4</li>
  <li class="class-5">5</li>
</ul>
```

How can i get length of li elems?
like this `document.querySelector(.wrapper > li).length`

cy.get('.wrapp > li').length does not  work

Answer (score 2):

Like it is said in [Cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/its.html#Arrays)

```
cy.get('.wrapper li')       // this yields us a jquery object
  .its('length')
  .then(length =>{
    //code that uses the length
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
cy.get('.wrapper').find('li').its('length').then((len) => {
    //Do stuff with length
    expect(len).to.equal(5)
})
```